# Solubility of salts in water

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions

I came across the formula for enthalpy of solution, which is equal to the sum of lattice enthalpy and hydration enthalpy. Therefore, for salts that have endothermic dissolution, the lattice enthalpy has to be greater than hydration enthalpy. But if that is true, then how will the salt dissolve in water in the first place?

Comment: Spontaneity is not just based on enthalpy. Read up on Gibbs Free Energy and entropy. Also this should help with the problem at hand. https://opentextbc.ca/chemistry/chapter/11-1-the-dissolution-process/

Comment: your saying that since entropy increases in hydration(due to salt dissociating), the reaction is spontaneous?

Comment: yes.but you would need some energy to initiate the reaction.

Comment: that energy comes from hydration enthalpy?

Comment: In case of icepacks, you shake it to mix the components. so you would initiate the process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can dissolution reactions (e.g. dissolution of calcium chloride) be exothermic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/why-can-dissolution-reactions-e-g-dissolution-of-calcium-chloride-be-exotherm)